# Efficient bit operations

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

In C++ I want to encode the bits of 3 unsigned variables into one. More precisely, when the three variables are:

```
A: a3 a2 a1 a0
B: b3 b2 b1 b0
C: c3 c2 c1 c0
```

then the output variable shall contain such triples:

```
D: a3 b3 c3   a2 b2 c2   a1 b1 c1   a0 b0 c0
```

Let's assume that the output variable is large enough for all used bits. I have come up with

```
unsigned long long result(0);
unsigned a,b,c; // Some numbers to be encoded
for(int level=0;level<numLevels;++level)
{
    int q(1<<level); // SearchBit q: 1<<level
    int baseShift((3*level)-level); // 0,2,4,6
    result|=(   ((a&q)<<(baseShift+2)) | ((b&q)<<(baseShift+1)) | ((c&q)<<(baseShift)) );
}
```

...and it works sufficiently. But I wonder if there is a solution that does not require a loop that iterates over all bits separately.

Comment: is the number of bits fixed? because you could easily unroll the loop manually

Comment: Check `sizeof(unsigned long)` before you get too carried away - it's very likely less than 12. Why are you wanting to do this?

Comment: sizeof(..) is checked, yes. It is used for a tree data structure. The number of bits is not fixed. Typically 8-10 but can be more.

Comment: OK, you also say "Let's assume that the output variable is large enough for all used bits," but the example you show is too large to fit in an `unsigned long` on _any_ modern mainstream platform.

Comment: An unsigned long is 64 bits on LP64. But we can use unsigned long long also.

Comment: ... and unsigned long long is how big?  :)   That idea is interesting but in reality it doesn't change things on most platforms these days: https://godbolt.org/z/-t4Id5

Comment: An unsigned long long has 64 bits on any relevant platform but let's assume that we have checked the output size before and numLevels has been adapted. Thank you for these hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a table mapping all or part of your bits to where they end up.  Shift values appropriately.

```
unsigned long long encoder(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned c) {
    static unsigned const encoding[16] = {
        0b0000000000,
        0b0000000001,
        0b0000001000,
        0b0000001001,
        0b0001000000,
        0b0001000001,
        0b0001001000,
        0b0001001001,
        0b1000000000,
        0b1000000001,
        0b1000001000,
        0b1000001001,
        0b1001000000,
        0b1001000001,
        0b1001001000,
        0b1001001001,
    };

    unsigned long long result(0);

    int shift = 0;
    do {
        result += ((encoding[a & 0xF] << 2) | (encoding[b & 0xF] << 1) | encoding[c & 0xF]) << shift;
        shift += 12;
        a >>= 4;
        b >>= 4;
        c >>= 4;
    } while (a || b || c);
    return result;
}
```

`encoding` defines a table to map 4 bits into their encoded locations.  This used directly for `c`, and shifted 1 or 2 bits for `b` and `a`.  If you have more than 4 bits to process, the next 4 bits in the source values are offset 12 bits further to the left.  Keep doing this until all nonzero bits have been processed.

This could use a `while` loop instead of a `do/while` but checking for zero before starting is useless unless most of the encodings are of all zero values.

If you frequently use more than 4 bits, the encoding table can be expanded and appropriate changes made to the loop to process more than 4 bits at a time.

Comment: Got the idea. Thank you, this is a great answer.